# How to version an XCode project for open source project?

Tags: xcode, git, github, version-control, version

I'm preparing to open source an XCode project I've been working on privately, on Github.

I am planning on using Github's release feature and and tag the initial release as 0.1.0. This much I know.

But I have one question: What's the best practice for the version number and build id of the XCode project itself going forward?

Do I need to update the version/build-id every time raise a version on Github?
Should these numbers be synchronized?

p.s.
I know some people may try to close this saying this is "off topic" for Stackoverflow, but trust me I tried asking everywhere else and nobody answered. And I do think this type of question is relevant to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm not clear on your question, but I can recommend best practices to follow http://semver.org

Answer (score 0):

For the 2cd question, whether you need to update the version on GitHub depend on you. If you make huge changes for your code, maybe you can create a new release.